# Common service file for reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I want to make a common service file structure for calling external apis in reactJs. Can anyone please suggest and give some sample demo code?

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function GetAllAuthorizationElements() {

    let response = null;
    await fetch(baseUrl + "/yourroute", {
        headers: defaultHeader
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then(data => response = data);

    if (!IsAuthorized(response)) {
        alert("Unauthorized")
        return 403;
    }

    return response;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to share some file structure with some demo example?

Comment: You just create a file for example "DataService.js" and you just paste my code above into this file. 

In case you want to use this function just type in "GetAllAuthorizationElements();"  in your jsx file.